# imageAvailableCallback never called in basic GPUImage2 camera setup

Tags: ios, swift, camera, gpuimage

I have followed the basic setup instructions on GPUImage2's github for [filtering live video](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2#filtering-live-video) and [capturing an image from video](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2#capturing-an-image-from-video) just so I can setup a basic camera. When the user taps a button, I try to capture the image from the filter using this code specifically:

```
    let pictureOutput = PictureOutput()
    pictureOutput.encodedImageFormat = .JPEG
    pictureOutput.imageAvailableCallback = {image in
        // Do something with the image
        self.previewImageView.image = image
    }
    self.filter! --> pictureOutput
```

For whatever reason, the imageAvailableCallback is never called and I am unable to get the image from the camera.

Comment: I'm betting this is an object lifetime issue. Try making `pictureOutput` a property on the enclosing class to extend its lifetime and see if the callback is triggered then. Weak links go from source to target, with strong links going from target back to source. With a transient endpoint like a PictureOutput, I need to artificially extend lifetimes, but I may not have done it for the case where callbacks are set directly (I do this when saving to URLs).

Comment: thank you @BradLarson that seemed to be the issue. I assumed which variables needed to be class properties when the other instructions didn't include let or var, so maybe removing the "let" before "pictureOutput" would make it that obvious.

Comment: What it really points to is a flaw in my memory management architecture around that particular class. I need to find a reliable way for it to hang around long enough to get you the image out of this.

Comment: I confirm this problem and solution

Answer (score 1):

The `-->` calls `addTarget` and `addTarget` appends to targets (`TargetContainer`) which appends a weak reference. So you should make sure the target will be available on callback. For example just place the pictureOutput variable at the top of your class.