# Capturing still image from camera using gpuimage2

Tags: ios, ipad, swift3, gpuimage

I have a photo/gif app I made previously using AVFoundation as a base for the camera and taking photos, but I wanted to upgrade it to add some live filtering and post capture filtering too.

After some digging I found gpuimage/gpuimage2 and since my project is in swift 3 I started replacing my previous camera module with gpuimage.

I got the camera to work again but I have issues capturing a photo from the camera to store it as a uiimage until it is uploaded to a server.

```
do {
  self.videoCamera = try Camera(sessionPreset: AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto, location: .frontFacing)
} catch {
  self.videoCamera = nil
  print("Couldn't initialize camera with error: \(error)")
}
```

this is my init and then this is where I place the camera feed in the view

```
self.filterView!.frame = self.view.frame
self.filterView!.orientation = .portraitUpsideDown
self.filterView!.fillMode = .preserveAspectRatioAndFill
self.videoCamera! --> self.filterView!
self.videoCamera!.startCapture()
```

as you can see for the moment I don't want to use any filters, I'm trying to first get the basic functionality back (i.e. showing a camera feed the taking 1-5 images in a row)

I noticed there was a saveNextFrameToURL but it saves the file on the device but I only want the uiimage  so this is what I put to replace the content of my takePhoto method (images is nil on first run)

```
func takePhoto(){
  if self.images == nil {
    self.images = []
  }
  let pictureOutput = PictureOutput()
  pictureOutput.encodedImageFormat = .jpeg
  pictureOutput.imageAvailableCallback = {image in
    self.images!.append(image)
  }
  self.videoCamera! --> pictureOutput
}
```

My issue is that imageAvailableCallback is simply never called (I tried placing a breakpoint in it but nothing) whereas it goes through the rest of the method not raising any errors or warning.

what am I doing wrong ? is it even possible to capture a still image from a non filtered view ? if so how can I add a filter that would not change the image as such so I can still do some unedited photo capture in my app?

I've been going at it for over 2 weeks now and every time I search if anyone had the same issue I only find issues about editing a still image or a filtered image and when I tried filtering the image as such:

```
self.filterView!.frame = self.view.frame
self.filterView!.orientation = .portraitUpsideDown
self.filterView!.fillMode = .preserveAspectRatioAndFill
self.baseFilter = BrightnessAdjustment()
self.videoCamera! --> self.baseFilter --> self.filterView!
self.videoCamera!.startCapture()
```

and the takePhoto method

```
func takePhoto(){
  if self.images == nil {
    self.images = []
  }
  let pictureOutput = PictureOutput()
  pictureOutput.encodedImageFormat = .jpeg
  pictureOutput.imageAvailableCallback = {image in
    self.images!.append(image)
  }
  self.baseFilter! --> pictureOutput
}
```

I get a white screen instead of my camera feed and still no image.

Any help would be appreciated thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where my problem was by looking at similar issues and the comments (found one where Brad Larson commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37687753/imageavailablecallback-never-called-in-basic-gpuimage2-camera-setup)

Basically it has to do with the lifespan of my pictureOutput variable, since it was enclosed inside a method is didn't last long enough for the callback to be made and to save the image, by making my pictureOutput variable a class variable I solved my issues